# Check if a number upto 120 is a prime

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

**NEWEST PROBLEM:** (Trying to check if it is divisible by 2)

```
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
    MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
    DIV two ;div 123 / 2;
    CMP AH,0
    JNE inputIsPrime

    ;If 123 % 2 = 0, output 123 / 2.
    DIV ten
    MOV DH,AH

    SUB AL,'0'
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21h

    MOV divisionCalc,DH

    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,DH
    INT 21h
    JMP endProg
```

I'm trying to accomplish this:

1. Input number upto 120. Let's call it "num".
2. If the number's remainder with 2,3,5,7,11 is zero, I need to print the division with each number that its remainder is zero. Otherwise, if print that num is a prime numbe.

> e.g.
>
> input: 120. output: 120 / 2 = 60, 120 / 3 = 40.
>
> input: 118, output: 118 is prime.

What I've done:

1. I scan  the first 3 digits (I don't care if first digits are zero) and I use an easy algorithm to build 'num'. also I assume the number is smaller than 121.
2. if the number is divisible by any of (2,3,5,7,11) I print the msg, otherwise I skip the msg print.
3. if all remainder with the number is zero, I print that num is a prime number.

I'm not sure if I accomplished that because I'm having some problems running DOSBox, can you help me determine if I did that right?

**SOLUTION**:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA

DisplayString DB 'Enter number up to 120:', 13,10,'$'
isPrimeNum DB 'is prime', 13,10,'$'
ResultStr DB 13,10, '    /    =   ' , 13,10,'$'
divisionCalc DB ?
myNum DB ?
two DB 2
three DB 3
five DB 5
seven DB 7
ten DB 10
eleven DB 11

    .CODE
Begin:
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    
    MOV AH,9
    MOV DX,OFFSET DisplayString
    INT 21h
    
    MOV BL,0 ; Initialize BL to zero!
    
    ; //READ 3 DIGITS // ;
    ;read first digit for e.g. '1'
    MOV ah,1h
    INT 21h ;read into AL
    MOV CL,AL
    MOV ResultStr[2], AL
    SUB AL,'0' ; Convert the digit from ASCII to DECIMAL
    MOV myNum,AL
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21h
    CMP AL,13 ;is it Enter?
    JE endInput
    MOV ResultStr[3], AL
    SUB AL,'0' ;Not enter, let's save this new char
    MOV CL, AL ; we save the 2nd char to CL
    MOV AL, myNum ; lets move our first char to AL
    MUL Ten ; multiply by 10 the first char
    MOV myNum,AL ;move that to myNum
    ADD myNum,CL ; add to AL the 2nd char.
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21h
    
    CMP AL,13 ; is it enter?
    JE endInput
    MOV ResultStr[4], AL
    SUB AL,'0' ;Not enter, let's save this new char
    MOV CL, AL ; we save the 2nd char to CL
    MOV AL, myNum ; lets move our first char to AL
    MUL Ten ; multiply by 10 the first char
    MOV myNum,AL ;move that to myNum
    ADD myNum,CL ; add to AL the 2nd char.
    
    mov AH,1 ; if the number is 3 chars then this will be the enter now. 
    int 21h 
    
    ; // FINISH READING 3 DIGITS // ;
    endInput:
    
            ; AL = AX / two
        ; AH = AX % two
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
mov CL,[myNum]
DIV two ;div 123 / 2;
CMP AH,0
JNE divThree

;If 123 % 2 = 0, output 123 / 2.

MOV ResultStr[9], '2'

DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

ADD AL,'0'
MOV ResultStr[13], AL
ADD DH,'0'
MOV ResultStr[14], DH

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
INT 21h

divThree:
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
DIV three ;div 123 / 3;
CMP AH,0
JNE divFive

;If 123 % 3 = 0, output 123 / 3.
MOV ResultStr[9], '3'

DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

ADD AL,'0'
MOV ResultStr[13], AL
ADD DH,'0'
MOV ResultStr[14], DH


MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
INT 21h

divFive:
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
DIV five ;div 123 / 5;
CMP AH,0
JNE divSeven

;If 123 % 5 = 0, output 123 / 5.
MOV ResultStr[9], '5'

DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

ADD AL,'0'
MOV ResultStr[13], AL
ADD DH,'0'
MOV ResultStr[14], DH

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
INT 21h

divSeven:
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
DIV seven ;div 123 / 7;
CMP AH,0
JNE divEleven

;If 123 % 7 = 0, output 123 / 7.
MOV ResultStr[9], '7'

DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

ADD AL,'0'
MOV ResultStr[13], AL
ADD DH,'0'
MOV ResultStr[14], DH

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
INT 21h

divEleven:
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
DIV eleven ;div 123 / 11;
CMP AH,0
JE Skip1
JMP inputIsPrime

Skip1:
;If 123 % 11 = 0, output 123 / 11.
MOV ResultStr[8], '1'
MOV ResultStr[9], '1'

DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

ADD AL,'0'
MOV ResultStr[13], AL
ADD DH,'0'
MOV ResultStr[14], DH

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
INT 21h

JMP endProg

inputIsPrime:
MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET isPrimeNum
INT 21h

endProg:
MOV AH,4Ch
INT 21h
END Begin
```

Comment: Aside: you don't need to check `11` because it is greater than square root of `120`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, the program is terminated after I input a number from 0-120

Comment: As to number entry char by char. The algorithm is initialise an accumulator to `0`. Then for each digit entered, it should be `accum = accum * 10 + digit` although you correctly make the ASCII adjustment..

Comment: @WeatherVane I do that with BL.

Comment: You do not initialise `BL` with `10`. And `MUL` does not multiply by `BL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've added now 'MOV BL,0' in the beginning of my code. and I use 'MUL' with the 'num'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107369/discussion-between-ilan-aizelman-ws-and-weather-vane). @WeatherVane

Comment: For numbers up to 120; use a precomputed "1 bit per number" bitfield (total cost is 15 bytes) and an instruction like `bt [bitfield],cx` (where CX is the number). If you're having trouble converting ASCII into an integer then change the topic title.

Comment: @Brendan I edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one rule in programming is "don't repeat yourself". so each time you copy code, you should ask yourself if you can avoid it. Instead of checking each prime in a separate code block, you could use an "array" of primes

```
num     db 118
prims   db 2,3,5,7,11           ; these pimes will be checked
```

and then check each of them in a loop like this:

```
start:  mov cx, 5               ; number of prims to check
        mov si, offset prims

checkPrime:
        xor ah, ah              ; this is faster than mov ah,0
        mov al, [num]
        div byte ptr [si]

        cmp ah,0
        jne skip

        ;...                    ; here you do whatever you want to do with non-primes
                                ; or even jump out of the loop, if all you want is to 
                                ; determine if [num] is a prime

skip:   inc si
        dec cx
        jnz checkPrime
```

ps: also you're "scan in 3 digits" was better if you made it with a loop, e.g. if you want to extend it to read 5 digits, or even a variable amount, like 1-5 digits to enter a 16bit int.
Also i'd separate the "enter a digit" part from the "decode ascii and make an int of it" parts, (enter ALL chars into a buffer first, THEN decode it)  you probably want to reuse them;
you could also use function int 21/A, for a buffered input of the complete value

Comment: Tommy, thx for your reply. I've edited my code in the post. can you take a look? I want to print 60 / 2 = 30, and I want to print 30. so I divide it by 10, and print 3 from AL, and 0 from AH. which doesn't work. it prints an ascii sign like heart, or other signs, do u know why?

Comment: to print 30, you have to print ASCII '3' and ASCII '0'. Add a '0' to your digit values before you print em (you subtracted '0' for each digit when you entered them, you remember? it's the same thing)

Comment: Finally, after 4 hours .. but why I needed to ADD and not SUB?!

Comment: ascii '0' - '9' is values 0x30 - 0x39. so if you enter ascii, you have to SUB 0x30 from each digit, and when displaying them, you need to ADD 0x30

Comment: you got it. just like ascii --> bin, but the other way round. split it into digits, ascii adjust, and display them

Comment: Tommy and @IlanAizelmanWS: I'd probably peel the `%2` check out of the loop, since it's worth increasing the code-size a bit to avoid a `div`: do it with `test [num], 1` / `jz .even`.  Also note that you could save code-size in your loop by loading `[num]` into a 16bit reg with the upper half zeroed.  (e.g. `movzx dx, byte ptr [num]`).  Then inside the loop, replace xor/load with `mov ax, dx` or something.  Checking the div result with `test ah,ah` is slightly better than `cmp ah, 0`

Comment: @peter cordes cant use loops

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: then just fully-unroll Tommylee's loop, duh.  And you should have said that you weren't allowed to use loops, because it's the only good answer for a really repetitive task like this.  A full unroll will be very bloated and hard to read, like your code in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes last bug. When I enter "113" it prints is prime. which is good. when I print 120, it prints the division with 2,3,5. but it then prints is prime too. which is a bug. any ideas? (in the solution code)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: IDK, I don't want to read that giant wall of messy code.  Single-step with a debugger and see when 120 takes a different path from other compound numbers, like 110.  (Also, have a look at the x86 tag wiki.  There's a link about style/formatting to make code easier to read).

Comment: @PeterCordes Solved it. with counter which determines if it is a prime number.

Comment: :) I think Ilan just went into the trap, that when the loop is done, the number must be a prime, which isnt the cast. it's just a prime when the inner part is __always__ skipped.